# Updating Matrix Array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to make a grid that looks like this in javascript using one function:

x---------
xx--------
xxx-------
xxxx------
xxxxx-----
xxxxxx----
xxxxxxx---
xxxxxxxx--
xxxxxxxxx-
xxxxxxxxxx

and this:

x---------
xx--------
xxx-------
xxxx------
xxxxx-----
xxxxx-----
xxxx------
xxx-------
xx--------
x---------

```
//Build Matrix
function initMatrix(max) {
var myMatrix = [];
var i;
for(i = 0; i < row; i++){
    myMatrix.push([]);
    var j;
    for(j = 0; j < col; j++) {
        if(j < max) {
            myMatrix[myMatrix.length - 1].push('*');
        } else {
           myMatrix[myMatrix.length - 1].push('-');
        }
    }
}
return myMatrix;
```

}

More of this code can be viewed here

https://jsfiddle.net/0yc7acev/

Thanks in advanced for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi I've made you this document that explains how to do this and has both solutions: https://tonicdev.com/tonic/stars-example . Let me know if you have any questions!

Edit: I realized after the fact that you wanted them in a matrix, not a string, so I've made a slight modification to put them in a matrix for you: https://tonicdev.com/tonic/stars-matrix (the old one still shows how to put them all in string).

The solution at the end is just:

```
function drawStars(starCounts)
{
    return starCounts.map(function (starCount)
    {
        return (new Array(starCount + 1).join("*") + 
                new Array(lineLength - starCount + 1).join("-")).split("")
    });
}
```

where starCounts is an array.

Comment: Answers should be posted here as links may not survive. You can post runable code snippets in the answer.

Comment: I did post the answer here as well.

Comment: The code, but not the answer: "*…I've made you this document that explains how to do this…*".

Comment: This is an incredible help!  Thank you so much!

Comment: **UPDATE** (here are is actual written problem): Draw a 10x10 grid.  You will be given a list of points.  If you were not given a point on a given row, select a point that is between the row before and after.  Be careful, you could have multiple missing rows between points and need to think of a way to gradually add asteriks between the points.

For example, given the points 0x0 and 9x9 the grid should look like the following:

-first grid (above).

then how would draw the second grid (above) using that same function